# SPFX MSGraphClient - Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, react, ms-graph-client

I am getting this issue when calling Shared and Recent OneDrive files using MS Graph Client on my modern webpart.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

I get the response OK.

using `/me/drive/sharedWithMe` and `/me/drive/recent`
if I just `console.log` it lists the ids.

It occurs when pushing the id into the items array.

it works fine with `/me/drive/root/children` and if I send a drive-id & item id for example `/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item_id}/children`

```
if (response) {
    console.log(response)
    response.value.map((item: any) => {
       console.log(item.id)
       items.push({
          key:item.id
          ...
       });
    });
}
```

I've tried

```
var i:any;
var item:any;
for (i in response.value) {
   item=response.value[i];
   console.log(item.id)
   items.push({
        key:item.id
        ...
   });
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine when I debug in my local, you could try to debug your code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes this works for me, if I debug without pushing it into an array.

Comment: Can you push in to an array?

Answer (score 0):

Try below solutions:

```
var items = response.value.map(obj => ({
    key: obj.id
}))
```

**OR**

```
var items = [];
var len = response.value.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    items.push({
        key: response.value[i].id,
    });
}
```

**Reference**:

[How to create an array of object literals in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290131/how-to-create-an-array-of-object-literals-in-a-loop).

Comment: I've tried these with no success. its strange how it only happens on /me/drive/sharedWithMe & /me/drive/recent

Comment: Are you getting any error while using this solutions?

Comment: yes its the same error